# onclick event on image element in fire fox os

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-os

```
     function listContents(storagename) {

        alert("inside function");
        //Clear up the list first
            $('#results').html("");
            var files = navigator.getDeviceStorage(storagename);

            var cursor = files.enumerate();

            cursor.onsuccess = function () {
              //alert("Got something");
              var file = this.result;
              if (file != null) {
        var imageElement = $('<img height="100" width="75">');
              imageElement.attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
              var tagvalue=  $("<p>" + file.name + "," + file.lastModifiedDate + "," + file.type + "," + file.size  + "</p>").appendTo('#results');
              imageElement.appendTo("#results");
                this.done = false;
              }
              else {
                this.done = true;
              }

              if (!this.done) {
                this.continue();
              }
            }
}

imageElement.onclick = function() { 
console.log('onclick function!');
//alert('blah');
}
```

I am retrieving audio file list from SDCard in Firefox OS. Now I want to upload this file to server so for that when I do `onclick` on image element I am able to do any event so I am trying to display alert box but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your sniplet `imageElement` is not visible outside `listContents` function, you need to register onclick handler in other way, by binding.

```
$('#results > img').on('click', function() { 
  console.log('onclick function!');
  //alert('blah');
});
```

Or register it inside inside listContents function.

Secondly if you are using jQuery, stick to it, use `click()`, `on()` methods, instead plain javascript events (`onclick`  in your example)

As a tip: to clean element content use empty function, like so:

```
$('#results').empty();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767442/button-event-is-not-working-in-fire-fox-os  hey i have made some changes like instead of image element i am creating button but still it is not working.not showing alert box.here link is there.plz hepl me to resolve this issue

Comment: @user3679542 If you have moved this question, please close/resolve this one, we would like to keep stact as clean as possible :)